# Render CCK widget only

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms

Is there a way to render only the widget of a CCK field (e.g., series of checkboxes) using $form on a node add/edit form (via *.tpl.php) without going into the content type itself and hiding the label? I seem to be unable to render a series of checkboxes without the label showing up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in your template file for the content type's add/edit form, simply add something like:

`<?php $form['field_FIELDNAME']['value']['#title'] = FALSE; ?>`

or

`<?php unset($form['field_FIELDNAME']['value']['#title']); ?>`

replacing "FIELDNAME" with the name you chose when creating the field.

Comment: Is there a reason why "unset" doesn't work as per here?: http://drupal.org/node/601646

Comment: Seems unset works as well as per the link I posted. I believe that page was edited recently.